# How to print data character by character in vertical form in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I want to know is their any other approach to get character by character data in vertical form as shown below in output

**my code :**

```
select substr('vikas',level, 1) from dual
connect by level <= length('vikas');
```

**Output :**

```
v
i
k
a
s
```

*It will be helpful for me in interview , any other approach to get the same above output*

Comment: A recursive cte?

Comment: @jarlh : can you share the approach or solution

Answer (score 3):

How about regular expressions?

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('vikas', '(.)', '\1' || chr(10)) val
  2  from dual;

VAL
----------
v
i
k
a
s


SQL>
```

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate step by step what actually it is doing

Comment: it not working bro

Comment: It *is* working (as demonstrated), in SQL*Plus. If you're doing it in SQL Developer, then you don't see such an output unless you click the result and the pencil icon (see the edited answer). What does it do? It "scrolls" through the string, letter-by-letter, and concatenates linefeed character (chr(10)) to it so that it produces result you want.

Comment: Can you explain what is `(.)`  `'\1'`

Comment: A dot represents *any character*. Enclosed into parentheses, it is treated as a *subexpression*, a string that contains just one character. \1 represents a *backreference* and matches the 1st preceding subexpression (i.e. a character enclosed in parentheses). Read more about Oracle regexp here (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm)